# Ignore AuthenticationContext In SAML2 Response

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-5, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

We have an asp.net 5 web app that will serve as a Service Provider to our users.
We have chosen `ITfoxtec Identity SAML 2.0` library for this purpose.
The request is successful, but in the response we get the following error:

> System.ArgumentException: IDX13300: 'System.String' must be an absolute Uri, was: 'System.Uri'

For completeness here is the full stack trace:

> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityTokenReadException: IDX13102: Exception thrown while reading 'System.String' for Saml2SecurityToken. Inner exception: 'System.ArgumentException'.
> ---> System.ArgumentException: IDX13300: 'System.String' must be an absolute Uri, was: 'System.Uri'
> at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2AuthenticationContext.set_DeclarationReference(Uri value)
> at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2Serializer.ReadAuthenticationContext(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2Serializer.ReadAuthenticationContext(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
> at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2Serializer.ReadAuthenticationStatement(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
> at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2Serializer.ReadAssertion(XmlReader reader)
> at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.ReadSaml2Token(XmlReader reader)
> at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.ReadSaml2Token(String token)
> at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2AuthnResponse.ReadSecurityToken(String tokenString)
> at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2AuthnResponse.Read(String xml, Boolean validateXmlSignature)
> at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2PostBinding.Read(HttpRequest request, Saml2Request saml2RequestResponse, String messageName, Boolean validateXmlSignature)
> at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2Binding1.ReadSamlResponse(HttpRequest request, Saml2Response saml2Response)
> at SsoGovILApi.Controllers.SamlController.AssertionConsumerService() in F:\Dev\ashilon\SsoGovIlApi\Controllers\SamlController.cs:line 45
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask1 actionResultValueTask)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.UsePathBaseMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT1.ProcessRequestAsync()

I have looked up the error and found that the authentication context can be ignored, and some libraries give this option, like this one for example:
[IgnoreAuthenticationContextInResponse compatibility flag](https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/issues/1045)

Is there a way to this in the ITfoxtec library too?

Thanks in advance,
ashilon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement you own version of `Saml2AuthnResponse` and on the `Saml2SecurityTokenHandler` property set your own implementation of `Saml2ResponseSecurityTokenHandler`.

I think it should be possible to change the authentication context validation in your own implementation of the `Saml2ResponseSecurityTokenHandler`.

Comment: Thanks Anders, but I found an easier way to get around this. I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: I'm wondering why the signature still validates?

Comment: You are correct. I'm getting a signature error.

Comment: I also bumped into this issue with a new IdP. It could be nice, if the library could be configured to handle this issue. Also this user is having the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69830260/authncontextdeclref-issue

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue myself, also with an Idp that sent a non compliant AuthnContextClassRef.
At least with .net core it's possible to avoid the error with a minimal change in Saml2AuthnResponse without needing a custom Saml2ResponseSecurityTokenHandler:
The tokenstring passed to ReadSecuritytoken/ReadClaimsIdentity can be safely modified without impacting signature verification. Modified Read method in Saml2AuthnResponse:

```
var tokenString = assertionElement.OuterXml;
if (this.TokenProcessor != null)
{
    tokenString = this.TokenProcessor.ProcessToken(tokenString);
}
Saml2SecurityToken = ReadSecurityToken(tokenString);
ClaimsIdentity = ReadClaimsIdentity(tokenString, detectReplayedTokens);
```

Providing a property for a method to manipulate the tokenString works just fine. Implementing my own Saml2AuthnResponse seems a bit overkill and creating a derived class that just replaces the read method does not seem to be viable due to the protection level.

Answer (score -1):

As a simple workaround for this problem, what I did was to simply remove the `saml:AuthnContextDeclRef` element from the response's xml.
Here's the code, in POC state, before cleaning up:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> AssertionConsumerService()
    {
        var binding = new Saml2PostBinding();
        var saml2AuthnResponse = new Saml2AuthnResponse(_config);

        var httpRequest = Request.ToGenericHttpRequest();

        // Remove AuthnContextDeclRef element
        var samlResponseXml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(httpRequest.Form["SAMLResponse"] ?? string.Empty));
        var root = XElement.Parse(samlResponseXml);
        XNamespace ns = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion";
        root.Element(ns + "Assertion")?.Element(ns + "AuthnStatement")?.Element(ns + "AuthnContext")?.Element(ns + "AuthnContextDeclRef")?.Remove();
        httpRequest.Form["SAMLResponse"] = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(root.ToString()));

        binding.ReadSamlResponse(httpRequest, saml2AuthnResponse);
        if (saml2AuthnResponse.Status != Saml2StatusCodes.Success)
        {
            throw new AuthenticationException($"SAML Response status: {saml2AuthnResponse.Status}");
        }
        binding.Unbind(httpRequest, saml2AuthnResponse);
        await saml2AuthnResponse.CreateSession(HttpContext, claimsTransform: ClaimsTransform.Transform);

        var relayStateQuery = binding.GetRelayStateQuery();
        var returnUrl = relayStateQuery.ContainsKey(RelayStateReturnUrl) ? relayStateQuery[RelayStateReturnUrl] : Url.Content("~/");
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
```

Comment: I understand the downvote as it is might be helpful for others to not do it like that, no shortcuts, there is a proper way to do it. Thanks.